# Does Snowflake store all data in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's say I import some data from on-prem SQL Server to Snowflake. Where does this data get stored?

In the Snowflake website it [says](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-key-concepts.html#database-storage):

> When data is loaded into Snowflake, Snowflake reorganizes that data
> into its internal optimized, compressed, columnar format. **Snowflake
> stores this optimized data in cloud storage.**

Does cloud storage mean S3 in case of AWS? If not, what then?

Comment: Short, basic answer: yes. But there could be more nuance to the answer depending on why are you wondering abou this.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Thanks. I want to know how Snowflake works. One key piece is where all the data is stored.

Comment: Let's approach this question from a different place: If the data is not stored in S3, where else could it be stored?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Please see my last comment on Mike's answer. If my statement in that comment is correct, it shows how it has been a source of misunderstanding.

Comment: Let's say "all data is safely stored in S3". Is that the answer you are looking for? Can you explain why this answer would not be satisfactory to you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The data is ultimately stored on S3.

A more complete answer for you:

http://info.snowflake.net/rs/252-RFO-227/images/Snowflake_SIGMOD.pdf

Comment: Can we say S3 is the only data source that Snowflake can read from (for Snowflake in AWS)?

Comment: How Snowflake stores its data and what data sources Snowflake can read from are 2 different things entirely.  I recommend reading up on Snowflake's data connectors.  What exactly are you interested in doing?

Comment: I just want to understand how it works. What I meant was for creating tables. Because based on my understanding Snowflake is built on S3. So I guessed all the data that needs to get "imported" into the tables in Snowflake need to be first stored in S3.

Comment: No, not necessarily.  You can import data in through various connectors without landing on S3, first.  However, it is the most efficient way to get data into Snowflake.

Comment: But what do you mean by importing "into" Snowflake without storing in S3? The physical storage location of all the Snowflake tables data is S3 itself. Am I wrong?

Comment: @LoMaPh you said "first stored in s3" which, to me, sounds like you thought you need to land the data in s3 before Snowflake could see it. This isn't the case. Snowflake handles the data in S3 and you can import it with SQL, JDBC, CSV, CLI etc. Just like how Postgres or Oracle would handle the files on the filesystem.